# Snapshot builds of stack available?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I need to use stack 1.3.3 in Travis CI due to a complication issue. The fix is not present in 1.3.2 and 1.3.3 has not been released yet. Currently, I am building stack myself from the source code in my Travis configuration. This adds time to the build. I would like to avoid that.

I am looking for snapshot builds of stack, but I have only seen where to get stable versions. Are snapshot builds of stack 1.3.3 available?

Thanks

Comment: No, there are no nightly/snapshot builds of stack available to my knowledge. But I'd think that you could just configure the Travis cache to save your `stack` binary.